# what multiline.pattern is good for my log in filebeat(elastic)?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, filebeat

please help me

what multiline.pattern is good for my log in filebeat?

*note:My log contains blank line in the middle.

Thanks a lot.

--my log

```
        2021-12-08 01:00:00.280 DEBUG --- [TaskScheduler-1] [c.i.f.g.c.d.d.d.DbOperationRepository   :] : run insert into PCK.ARCH_PCK_PRSN(id, id_typ, id_cd, id_nm, shb_id, prsn_typ, tx_id, rcpt_dt) SELECT t1.id, t1.id_typ, t1.id_cd, t1.id_nm, t1.shb_id, t1.prsn_typ, t1.tx_id, t1.rcpt_dt  FROM  FRD_DAILY.TEMP_PCK_PRSN t1 join FRD_DAILY.TEMP_PCK t0 on t1.tx_id=t0.tx_id where t0.rej_sts != 1 and t0.rcpt_dt >= to_date('2021-12-04', 'yyyy-MM-dd') and t0.rcpt_dt < to_date('2021-12-05', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        2021-12-08 01:00:00.327 ERROR --- [TaskScheduler-1] [c.i.f.g.c.c.e.InternalExceptionHandler  :] : خطای سیستمی
        org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_191]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
        Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
                at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[common-1.4.3-RELEASE.jar:?]
                at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
                ... 54 more
        Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "RCPT_DT": invalid identifier
        
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494) ~[jdbc-8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446) ~[jdbc-8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
                at com.isc.fmg.gs.core.domain.dao.db.DbOperationRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$873cbd0c.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[common-1.4.3-RELEASE.jar:?]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[common-1.4.3-RELEASE.jar:?]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[common-1.4.3-RELEASE.jar:?]
                at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
                ... 54 more
        Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "RCPT_DT": invalid identifier
        
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498) ~[jdbc-8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446) ~[jdbc-8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054) ~[jdbc-8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[common-1.4.3-RELEASE.jar:?]
                at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
                ... 54 more
        2021-12-08 01:03:00.001 DEBUG --- [TaskScheduler-2] [c.i.f.g.c.s.SchedulerLogger             :] : begin scheduler logger: 1638912780001
        2021-12-08 01:03:00.011 DEBUG --- [TaskScheduler-2] [c.i.f.g.c.c.c.CacheManager              :] : Loading current date ...
```

Comment: reasking the same question without any improvement won't help you getting an answer.

Comment: Everything is clear. 
i need a pattern for multiline.

Comment: You would want everything under a timestamp as a single event right?

Comment: yes , Exactly  
.